# XSLT: How to prevent duplicate element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml (... some elements and attributes omitted):

```
<root>
   ...
   <Auswertungsart Code="2"/>
   ...
   <Flaechenbezug Code="1"/>
   ...
</root>
```

I would like to insert a new element `Zeitbezug` before the element `Flaechenbezug` depending on the value of the `Code` attribute of the element `Auswertungsart`. When I transform it with this stylesheet and parameter value = 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:param name="Zeitbezug"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Flaechenbezug">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../Auswertungsart[not(@Code='1')]">
                <Zeitbezug Code="{$Zeitbezug}"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Zeitbezug/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this xml with the element `Zeitbezug` duplicated:

```
   <root>
      ...
      <Auswertungsart Code="2"/>
       ...
      <Zeitbezug Code="3"/>
      <Zeitbezug Code="3"/>
      <Flaechenbezug Code="2"/>
      ...
    </root>
```

How do I fix this?
Note: The value of the `Code` attribute is set from the parameter `Zeitbezug`

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the XML you omitted, for example, are there any other `Auswertungsart` or `Flaechenbezug` elements in the input?  If you run a test with only ONE of each in the input, do you get the desired results?

Comment: no, both elements only occur once. I suspect that what I insert, is also used in the copy-of select

Comment: No, the output tree does not participate in input processing.

Comment: Well, something you're not showing us is the culprit. I ran your XML (minus the `...` lines) and XSL in Oxygen and I get only one `Zeitbezug` output.

Comment: Yep, stupid me. Transformed twice...
But, thanks for clarifying that output tree does not participate in input processing

Comment: Please post a fuller snippet of XML for us to specifically help.